# Is there an in-built method in nltk to find words/phrases that closely match the given word?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, nltk

The speech recognition software that I'm using gives less than optimal results.

Eg: `session` is returned as `fashion` or `mission`.

Right now I have a dictionary like:

```
matches = {
  'session': ['fashion', 'mission'],
  ...
}
```

and I am looping over all the words to find a match.

I do not mind false positives as the application accepts only a limited set of keywords. However it is tedious to manually enter new words for each of them. Also, the the speech recognizer comes up with new words every time I speak.

I am also running into difficulties where a long word is returned as a group of smaller words, so the above approach won't work.

So, is there an in-built method in nltk to do this? Or even a better algorithm that I could write myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into python-Levenshtein. It's a python C extension module for calculating string distances/similarities.

Something like this silly inefficient code might work:

```
from Levenshtein import jaro_winkler  # May not be module name

heard_words = "brain"
possible_words = ["watermelon", "brian"]

word_scores = [jaro-winkler(heard_word, possible) for possible in possible_words]
guessed_word = possible_words[word_scores.index(max(word_scores))]

print('I heard {0} and guessed {1}'.format(heard_word, guessed_word))
```

Here's the [documentation](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/courses/LT1/2011/slides/Python-Levenshtein.html) and a non-maintained [repo](https://github.com/miohtama/python-Levenshtein).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **fuzzywuzzy**,a python package for fuzzy matching of words and strings.

To install the package.

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

Sample code related to your question.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 80

heard_word = "brain"

possible_words = ["watermelon", "brian"]

guessed_word = [word for word in possible_words if fuzz.ratio(heard_word, word) >= MIN_MATCH_SCORE]

print 'I heard {0} and guessed {1}'.format(heard_word, guessed_word)
```

Here is the [documentation and repo](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) of the **fuzzywuzzy**.